# Почему pylint в Visual Studio Code принимает за ошибку правильные части кода на Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, visual-studio-code

Код, который будет ниже, работает и не вызывает ошибок. Но почему-то pylint не воспринимает некоторые его части. Кому-то моя проблема может показаться смешной, но такое количество выделенного кода мешает сконцентрироваться на настощих ошибках. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как я могу наладить работу pylint, не отключая его полностью?

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Form(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.plainTextEdit.setFont(QFont('Arial', 11))

        openDirButton = QPushButton("Open Directory")
        openDirButton.clicked.connect(self.getDirectory)

        getFileNameButton = QPushButton("Open File")
        getFileNameButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileName)

        getFileNamesButton = QPushButton("Open Files")
        getFileNamesButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileNames)

        saveFileNameButton = QPushButton("Save File")
        saveFileNameButton.clicked.connect(self.saveFile)

        layoutV = QVBoxLayout()
        layoutV.addWidget(openDirButton)
        layoutV.addWidget(getFileNameButton)
        layoutV.addWidget(getFileNamesButton)
        layoutV.addWidget(saveFileNameButton)

        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addLayout(layoutV)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)

        centerWidget = QWidget()
        centerWidget.setLayout(layoutH) 
        self.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)

        self.resize(740,480)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5-QFileDialog")

    def getDirectory(self):                                                     # <-----
        dirlist = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Выбрать папку",".")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("<br>Выбрали папку: <b>{}</b>".format(dirlist))

    def getFileName(self):
        filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                             "Выбрать файл",
                             ".",
                             "Text Files(*.txt);;JPEG Files(*.jpeg);;\
                             PNG Files(*.png);;GIF File(*.gif);;All Files(*)")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("<br>Выбрали файл: <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^54}</b>"
                                      "".format(filename, filetype))

    def getFileNames(self):
        filenames, ok = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,
                             "Выберите несколько файлов",
                             ".",
                             "All Files(*.*)")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("""<br>Выбрали несколько файлов: 
                                       <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^80}</b>"""
                                      "".format(filenames, ok))

        folder = os.path.dirname(filenames[0])                                        
        print("folder =", folder)        
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("""<br>пути файлов, которые я выбираю: 
                                       <b>{}</b> """
                                      "".format(folder))        

    def saveFile(self):
        filename, ok = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
                             "Сохранить файл",
                             ".",
                             "All Files(*.*)")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("<br>Сохранить файл: <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^54}</b>"
                                      "".format(filename, ok))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, поможет unsafe-load-any-extension http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/c_extensions.html

Comment: Пробовал уйти от импорта через звездочку и явно импортировать классы?

Comment: @Alpensin, если делать так, как подсказываете вы, pylint ругаться не будет. Спасибо! Но, мне кажется, что это немного загромождает код:)

Comment: @andreymal, я не так давно начал учиться писать код и, возможно, многое не понимаю. Заранее прошу прощения за это. Моя операционная система - Windows, поэтому я не совсем понимаю, как мне воспользоваться данными командами. Я выполнил такие команды: 1) py 2)pylint --unsafe-load-any-extension=y К сожалению, все закончилось ошибкой

Comment: то, о чем написал  @Alpensi , очень важно, `все должно быть явным !` и вы не должны обращать внимание на то, что в ответах импорт через звездочку.

Comment: А еще можно навести мышку на то, что он подчеркнул и прочитать, почему `pylint` ругается. Частенько он пишет, что его не устраивает.

Comment: @MAXIM045 Правила форматирования кода изложены в документе PEP8. Цитата оттуда: "Wildcard imports (from <module> import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools. There is one defensible use case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a pure Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from an optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be overwritten isn't known in advance)."

Comment: @Alpensin, спасибо большое, я думал, что * делает код лучше. Пойду исправлять:)

Comment: Синтаксис - это красный кружок. желтый треугольник - неприличный стиль.  Это какслово "сука". Слово орфографически верное, но к девушке так лучше не обращаться. Это и значит желтый треугольник т pylint

Comment: @Alpensin, я исправил код, согласно вашему совету. Теперь pylint принял за ошибку **from**. Вот что пишет pylint: "No name 'QFont' in module 'PyQt5.QtGui'".  Буду искать причину